# Inline onclick JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I have a JavaScript above this html is there any way to pass it inside EditBanner(JS Variable Here) in code below ?

```
//EditBanner to be changed to pass a Js variable.
<input id="EditBanner" type="button" value="Edit Image" onclick="EditBanner();"/>
```

Comment: have you tried something like `onclick="EditBanner(myVar)"` ?

Comment: uh, what about _not_ in-lining your code?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There's an entire practice that says it's a bad idea to have inline functions/styles.
Taking into account you already have an ID for your button, consider

**JS**

```
var myvar=15;
function init(){
    document.getElementById('EditBanner').onclick=function(){EditBanner(myvar);};
}
window.onload=init;
```

**HTML**

```
<input id="EditBanner" type="button"  value="Edit Image" />
```

Comment: I agree best practice is to use event handlers, but inlining can and does work (doesn't scale well), just need to see what fits best for your project

Comment: Considering he already has an ID for the button and he sets myvar somewhere in the code, we can assume he already has a <script> tag where he can add event handlers and the means to get the correct element... There's no reason he should use inline events.

Comment: Of course it _can_ work -- but so does using GOTO and 3000-line methods. Not inlining is a best fit for any project.

Comment: Michael: "Not inlining is a best fit for any project" -- just put "almost", and you are 100% correct. (Just to let me do this 5-minute throwaway hack proto "project" with 7 lines of JS code to test out some Firebase behavior without expecting the Spanish inquisition. ;)

Answer (score 5):

```
<script>var myVar = 15;</script>
<input id="EditBanner" type="button" value="Edit Image" onclick="EditBanner(myVar);"/>
```

Comment: Shouldn't the first line be wrapped in a <script> tag?

Comment: @StevenLu: Yeah, it should.  I was just trying to point out how to use the variable.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, JavaScript variables will exist in the scope they are created.

```
var bannerID = 55;

<input id="EditBanner" type="button" 
  value="Edit Image" onclick="EditBanner(bannerID);"/>


function EditBanner(id) {
   //Do something with id
}
```

If you use event handlers and jQuery it is simple also

```
$("#EditBanner").click(function() {
   EditBanner(bannerID);
});
```

Comment: This does not work, you cannot use variables like that inside HTML.  Use `onclick="EditBanner(bannerID);"` instead