# Tomcat 7 manager - Disable "undeploy button"

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, undeploy

I upgraded from Tomcat 6 to Tomcat 7 and the manager differs some. In Tomcat 6's manager I would get a confirmation box when trying to stop or undeploy an app but in Tomcat 7 it just happens.

My questions is, can I disable or at least attach a confirmation javascript to the undeploy button?

Comment: were you able to solve this one? if not please post your findings

Comment: I would be very interested in a solution, too (or to know if you could solve the problem with the answer).

Answer (score 2):

The short answer version is NO, because the html is within the java class
**hardcoded** as you can see it here:

[HTMLManagerServlet](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/tomcat/trunk/java/org/apache/catalina/manager/HTMLManagerServlet.java)

But you can still do the following:

- extends HTMLManagerServlet and override the following method

  ```
  protected void list(HttpServletRequest request,
                      HttpServletResponse response,
                      String message,
                      StringManager smClient) throws IOException
  ```
- to use a different variable instead of :

  ```
  STARTED_DEPLOYED_APPS_ROW_BUTTON_SECTION, args));
  ```

and in **YOUR_STARTED_DEPLOYED_APPS_ROW_BUTTON_SECTION** variable you can inject your JS code that will handle the onclick event see this can be of help too:

[Inline onclick JavaScript variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5586857/inline-onclick-javascript-variable)

Then you compile your **YourHTMLManagerServlet** and change the manager/WEB-INF/web.xml **from:**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>HTMLManager</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
```

**to:**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>HTMLManager</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>your.own.YourHTMLManagerServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
```

put the jar with the **tomcat/lib** directory
and your ready to go.