# javascript function is undefined but my script is being loaded

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to master JavaScript and to practice I'm trying to make a reaction time test. The idea is very simple: you click on a button and after a random period of time the background changes colour and then you have to click on a second button which calls on a function that calculates your reaction time. Here is my JavaScript code:

```
function start(){
    console.log(start);
    var rndnr = (Math.round(Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1)) * 1000);
    setTimeout(function timeout() {
      document.bgColor="ffff00";
      start = new Date();
    }, rndnr);
}

function stop() {
    var onclick = new Date();
    var time = onclick-start;
    var total;
    var avg;
    var count = 1;
    document.getElementById("try 1").innerHTML = time;
    total = total + time;
    avg = total / count;
    count = count + 1;
    document.getElementById("avg1").innerHTML = avg;
}
```

and these are my buttons:

```
<button id="button" onclick="start()" >start</button>
<button onclick="stop()">stop</button>
```

When I try to execute the script I get an error in my console log which says this: `ReferenceError: start is not defined`. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: It seems like the functions are not declared in global scope?

Comment: What is the exact error-message? Is it: "ReferenceError: start is not defined" or "ReferenceError: start is not a function"?

Comment: You're likely trying to call the function before it is declared.

Comment: Have you waited until the dom has loaded?

Comment: start is a function and you redefine start holding a date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have quite a few typos in your code as well as some naming collisions and scope issues. This is your original code (aside from renaming `stop` to `stopF` since [`stop` is a global function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/stop) in a browser.

```js
function start() {
  console.log(start);
  // THE REFERENCE ERROR STEMS FROM THIS LINE PREVENTING THE FUNCTIONS
  //  FROM BEING DEFINED
  var rndnr = (Math.round(Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1)) * 1000);
  setTimeout(function timeout() {
    document.bgColor = "ffff00";
    start = new Date();
  }, rndnr);
}

function stopF() {
  var onclick = new Date();
  var time = onclick - start;
  var total;
  var avg;
  var count = 1;
  document.getElementById("try 1").innerHTML = time;
  total = total + time;
  avg = total / count;
  count = count + 1;
  document.getElementById("avg1").innerHTML = avg;
}
```

```html
<button id="button" onclick="start()">start</button>
<button onclick="stopF()">stop</button>
<div id="try 1"></div>
<div id="avg1"></div>
```

If you click "Run code snippet" you will notice an error in the console:

```
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
```

Because of this error, neither `start` nor `stopF` are defined. Therefore when the start button is clicked the inline JS would be evaluated and then attempt to find a non-existent `start` function resulting in a `ReferenceError`. Similarly if the stop button is clicked it will also log a `ReferenceError` for `stopF`.

Correcting some of the issues in the code gives:

```js
// You need to have a way of referencing the `start` variable (now `startTime`)
//  between the `start` and `stop` functions.
// You also need to be able to keep state for `total` and `count` between
//  subsequent calls to `stop`
// These issues can be solved by using scope variables
//  (here they are in the IIFE scope of the wrapper function)
var startTime;
var total = 0;
var count = 0;

// You had a name collision here within the scope of `start`
//  you also had attempted to use a variable named `start`
// Now the variable is called `startTime`
function start() {
  // You had an extra ')' in your expression assignment for `rndnr`
  var rndnr = (Math.round(Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1) * 1000);
  setTimeout(function timeout() {
    document.bgColor = "ffff00";
    startTime = new Date();
    // Since setTimeout is an async function console.log would be undefined
    //  until this function runs
    console.log(startTime);
  }, rndnr);
}

function stop() {
  var onclick = new Date();
  var time = onclick - startTime;
  var avg;
  total += time;
  avg = total / ++count;

  // You shouldn't include spaces in ID values as it can be confusing
  //  if this was intentional
  document.getElementById("try1").innerHTML = time;
  document.getElementById("avg1").innerHTML = avg;
  document.bgColor = "ffffff";
}
```

```html
<button id="button" onclick="start()">start</button>
<button onclick="stop()">stop</button>
<div id="try1"></div>
<div id="avg1"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

To ensure that the document knows about the `start` function, do something like:

```
window.start = function start(){ ... };
```

Or make sure to load your script before the handlers are assigned.

Secondly, don't try to set a value to start, since start refers to a function. Use `startTime` or another variable instead.

```
startTime = new Date();
```

Comment: While these are good suggestions they don't answer the OP's question. Please refer to [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31141237/3194372) for the reason for the ReferenceError.

Comment: @JasonCust They actually answer the question. `Uncaught ReferenceError: start is not defined` http://jsfiddle.net/sj4yz3a6/ http://jsfiddle.net/sj4yz3a6/1/ The OP didn't ask for his code to be fixed but for what is causing the issue.

Comment: The `ReferenceError` arises due to the JS engine not being able to parse the code for the function due to an extra ')'. While what you mention is worth noting, the function is never declared because of the `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )` error. I also fixed the code to point out other issues that would have impacted it after fixing that typo.

Comment: The OP didn't mention the `SyntaxError`so it's most likely that his question contains a slightly altered version of his original code.

Comment: Because of how inline JS works it is **the** reason for **both** errors. As the OP admits to being new to JS (or at least trying to master it) they probably didn't notice the `SyntaxError`. Or if they did notice it maybe they didn't think it was related. That said,  it is **because** of that `SyntaxError` the function is never defined and therefore when the inline JS is evaluated it attempts to execute a function that does not exist resulting in the `ReferenceError`. I just edited [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sj4yz3a6/2/) to show this. Check the console output.

Comment: You are just assuming that the OP is getting the `SyntaxError` while I assume that he does not. So my answer is just as correct and valid as any other correct answer until the OP confirms whether or not he was getting other errors.

Comment: Lets agree to disagree :D

Comment: I'm fine with that. Anyway it's up to the OP to pick the answer that fixes his problem. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Edited:

Here is a working version of your code (only the stop button needs the tags "try 1" and "avg")

http://jsfiddle.net/2q84yvzu/

The problem was on the extra ) on:

```
var rndnr = (Math.round(Math.floor(Math.random()*5)+1))*1000);
```

This is the correct version:

```
var rndnr = (Math.round(Math.floor(Math.random()*5)+1))*1000;
```

I changed the way of you bind the events to the elements, is not a good practice to embed the events inline. Instead try the next approach:

```
document.getElementById('start').onclick=function(){start();};
document.getElementById('stop').onclick=function(){stop();};
```

For more info on this, here is another question:

[Inline onclick JavaScript variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5586857/inline-onclick-javascript-variable)

Comment: While that is correct and probably not the OP's intention, how does this relate to the mentioned error?

Comment: Try logging a functions reference inside the function. It will not error in your console.

Answer (score 1):

```
var rndnr = (Math.round(Math.floor(Math.random()*5)+1))*1000);
```

syntax error,it should be

```
var rndnr = (Math.round(Math.floor(Math.random()*5)+1))*1000;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to rename variable `start` inside setTimeout function, because you override function start with date value after the first call of `start()` function.

```js
function f(){
    setTimeout(function(){ f = 1; }, 1000);
}

console.log(f); // function

f();

setTimeout(function(){ 
  console.log(f); // 1
}, 1100);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
console.log(start);
```

is wrong

It has to be

```
console.log("start");
```

or you have to create the variable start

```
var start = "put anything in here";
console.log(start);
```

Comment: start is the defined name of the function. it exists

Comment: Why would he want to print the function ?

Comment: start doesnt exist inside the function start. Thats the error. Thanks for downvote btw.

Comment: @Kbi While the OP does attempt to log the function (which seems to be a mistake) the error is not from that. That code is never executed. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31141237/3194372) for what causes the error.

Comment: @Kbi I downvoted because [you are wrong](http://jsfiddle.net/xvmkz5u2/). Ease the sarcasm and try it out.

Comment: How about telling it without downvoting :/