# Printing Id shows undefined in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I am calling a javascript function from my onclick passing this keyword as parameters.I need to print id of used in the div.But it shows undefined.

```
  <div class="btn-group" tabindex="0"><a class="btn active btn-danger"  onclick="functionTest(this)"  id="male" >Male</a><a class="btn btn-default" onclick="functionTest(this)" id="female">Female</a></div>
```

below is my function

```
function functionTest(obj){
    alert("ok");
    alert($(this).attr('id'));

}
```

`I am not getting my id,IT SHOWS UNDEFINED`.

Can anybody help me any help will be highly appreciable..

Comment: Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5586857/inline-onclick-javascript-variable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change 'this' to 'obj'

```
function functionTest(obj){
alert("ok");
alert($(obj).attr('id'));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First you will check your object name.

**this** will not work inside the function. You received the element as **obj**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `this` use `obj`:

```
alert($(obj).attr('id'));
```