# Javascript form calculation errors

Tags: javascript

Im getting uncaught type error for estimateCost, also im having issues with how to double the price with spouse. I'm suppose to have an alert window that displays the estimate cost based on selections made from city, number of days, and other options. TY!

```html
<html>

<head>

  <script language="JavaScript">
    var city_prices = new Array();
    city_prices["New York City"] = 0;
    city_prices["Boston"] = 0;
    city_prices["San Francisco"] = 200;
    city_prices["Los Angeles"] = 200;

     // getCityPrice() finds the price based on the city .
     // Here, we need to take user's the selection from radio button selection
    function getCityPrice() {
      var cityPrice = 0;
      //Get a reference to the form id="cakeform"
      var theForm = document.forms["form1"];
      //Get a reference to the cake the user Chooses name=radCity":
      var selectedCity = theForm.elements["radCity"];
      //Here since there are 4 radio buttons selectedCity.length = 4
      //We loop through each radio buttons
      for (var i = 0; i < selectedCity.length; i++) {
        //if the radio button is checked
        if (selectedCity[i].checked) {
          //we set cityPrice to the value of the selected radio button
          //i.e. if the user choose NYC we set to 0
          //by using the city_prices array
          //We get the selected Items value
          //For example city_prices["New York City".value]"
          cityPrice = city_prices[selectedCity[i].value];
          //If we get a match then we break out of this loop
          //No reason to continue if we get a match
          break;
        }
      }
      //We return the cityPrice
      return cityPrice;
    }

    var number_days = new Array();
    number_days["3"] = 450;
    number_days["4"] = 600;
    number_days["5"] = 750;
    number_days["6"] = 900;
    number_days["7"] = 1050;
    number_days["8"] = 1350;
    number_days["9"] = 1500;
    number_days["10"] = 1650;
    number_days["11"] = 1800;
    number_days["12"] = 1950;
    number_days["13"] = 2100;
    number_days["14"] = 2250;
    number_days["15"] = 2400;

     //This function finds the day price based on the
     //drop down selection
    function getDayPrice() {
      var dayPrice = 0;
      //Get a reference to the form id="form1"
      var theForm = document.forms["form1"];
      //Get a reference to the select id="selNumberDays"
      var selectedDays = theForm.elements["selNumberDays"];

      //set dayPrice equal to value user chose
      //For example number_days["3".value] would be equal to 450
      dayPrice = number_days[selectedDays.value];

      //finally we return dayPrice
      return dayPrice;
    }


     //chksFirst() finds the candles price based on a check box selection
    function chksFirst() {
      var chkFirst = 0;
      //Get a reference to the form id="form1"
      var theForm = document.forms["form1"];
      //Get a reference to the checkbox id="chkFirst"
      var includeFirst = theForm.elements["chkFirst"];

      //If they checked the box set first class to 500
      if (includeFirst.checked == true) {
        chkFirst = 500;
      }
      //finally we return the firstClass
      return chkFirst;
    }

     //chksSpouse() finds the candles price based on a check box selection
    function chksSpouse() {
      var chkSpouse = 0;
      //Get a reference to the form id="form1"
      var theForm = document.forms["form1"];
      //Get a reference to the checkbox id="chkSpouse"
      var includeSpouse = theForm.elements["chkSpouse"];

      //If they checked the box set Total 2x
      if (includeSpouse.checked == true) {
        totalPrice = totalPrice * 2;
      }
      //finally we return the firstClass
      return totalPrice;
    }


    function estimateCost() {
      //Here we get the estimate price by calling our function
      //Each function returns a number so by calling them we add the values they return together
      var totalPrice = getCityPrice() + getDayPrice() +
        chksFirst() + chksSpouse();

      alert(totalPrice);
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <table align="left" width="600px" border="0" cellpadding="5px">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <form name="form1" id="form1">
          <table border="0">
            <tr>
              <td width="300px"><strong>Last Name: </strong>
              </td>
              <td width="300px">
                <input type="text" name="txtFirstName" value=" " size="20" />
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td><strong>First Name: </strong>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" name="txtLastName" value=" " size="20" />
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td><strong>Nationality: </strong>
              </td>
              <td>
                <select name="selNationality">
                  <option value="amer">USA</option>
                  <option value="can">Canada</option>
                  <option value="mex">Mexico</option>
                  <option value="ger">Germany</option>
                  <option value="fra">France</option>
                </select>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td><strong>City you wish to visit: </strong>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="radio" name="radCity" value="New York City" />New York City
                <br />
                <input type="radio" name="radCity" value="Boston" />Boston
                <br />
                <input type="radio" name="radCity" value="San Francisco" />San Francisco ($200 surcharge)
                <br />
                <input type="radio" name="radCity" value="Los Angeles" />Los Angeles ($200 surcharge)
                <br/>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td><strong>Number of days ($150 per day): </strong>
              </td>
              <td>
                <select name="selNumberDays" id="selNumberDays">
                  <option value="3">3</option>
                  <option value="4">4</option>
                  <option value="5">5</option>
                  <option value="6">6</option>
                  <option value="7">7</option>
                  <option value="8">8</option>
                  <option value="9">9</option>
                  <option value="10">10</option>
                  <option value="11">11</option>
                  <option value="12">12</option>
                  <option value="13">13</option>
                  <option value="14">14</option>
                  <option value="15">15</option>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td><strong>Other options: </strong>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="chkFirst" id="chkFirst" />First Class Only ($500 surcharge)
                <br />
                <input type="checkbox" name="chkSpouse" id="chkSpouse" />Traveling with Spouse (All costs doubled)
                <br />
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="right">
                <input type="button" value="Give me an estimate!" onClick="estimateCost()" id="estimateCost" />
              </td>
              <td align="left">
                <input type="reset" />
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the button input with the `onClick="estimateCost()"` code, remove the `id="estimateCost"`. It's causing the error for some reason. You should really be using an onClick listener though instead of an inline onclick:
[Inline onclick JavaScript variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5586857/inline-onclick-javascript-variable)

For the total with spouse, you might want to rework it to something like this where you pass the pre-spouse price into the chksSpouse function and use it's return as the total price.

```
//chksSpouse() finds the candles price based on a check box selection
function chksSpouse(totalPrice) {
  var chkSpouse = 0;
  //Get a reference to the form id="form1"
  var theForm = document.forms["form1"];
  //Get a reference to the checkbox id="chkSpouse"
  var includeSpouse = theForm.elements["chkSpouse"];

  //If they checked the box set Total 2x
  if (includeSpouse.checked == true) {
    totalPrice = totalPrice * 2;
  }
  //finally we return the firstClass
  return totalPrice;
}

function estimateCost() {
  //Here we get the estimate price by calling our function
  //Each function returns a number so by calling them we add the values they return together
  var preSpouseTotal = getCityPrice() + getDayPrice() + chksFirst();
  var totalPrice = chksSpouse(preSpouseTotal);

  alert(totalPrice);
}
```

Comment: This is a consequence of a very old IE design feature to make element IDs into global variables referencing the element. It was seen as a very bad design decision at the time, but other browsers implemented it for compatibility.